# ECMAScript 6 - How do I pass a reference to "self" from within a class?

Tags: javascript, oop, ecmascript-6

How can I accomplish the following (as passing **this** does not achieve the desired result).  Referencing the line "this.AddComponent(new MoveComponent(0, 0, this));" in the "Square" class:

```
// shape.js
export default class Shape {
     constructor(name) {
         this.name = name;
         this.Components = [];
     }

     AddComponent(component) {
          this.Components.push(component);
     }
}

// component.js
export default class Component {
     constructor(name) {
          this.name = name;
     }
}

// square.js
import Shape from "./shape";
import MoveComponent from "./moveComponent";

export default class Square extends Shape {
     constructor() {
         super("square");
         this.AddComponent(new MoveComponent(0, 0, this));
     }
}

// moveComponent.js
import Component from "./component";

export default class MoveComponent extends Component {
     constructor(x, y, parentShape) {
          super("movement");
          this.x = x;
          this.y = y;
          this.ParentShape = parentShape;
     }
}
```

Comment: What specific error are you running into? `this` is what I'd expect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change to implementation of method `AddComponent` in the class `Shape` to this:

```
 AddComponent(component) {
     this.Components.push(component);
 }
```

```js
"use strict"

class Shape {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
    this.Components = [];
  }

  AddComponent(component) {
    this.Components.push(component);
    console.log(this)
  }
}

class Component {
  constructor(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
}

class Square extends Shape {
  constructor() {
    super("square");
    this.AddComponent(new MoveComponent(0, 0, this));
  }
}

class MoveComponent extends Component {
  constructor(x, y, parentShape) {
    super("movement");
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.ParentShape = parentShape;
  }
}

new Square() // logs passed arguments
```

Comment: And this fixes what problem in what way?

Comment: @torazaburo - originally code throws error that `Components` is undefined. Source of it was in the method declaration that was looking like `AddComponent(component) {
     components.push(component);
 }`